# How to pass multiple values to a monadic function

Tags: haskell

I have a program like bellow.

```
incVal :: Num a => a -> a
incVal x = x + 1

incVal' :: (Monad m, Num a) => a -> m a
incVal' x = return (x + 1)

incVal'' :: (Monad m, Num a) => a -> a -> m a
incVal'' x y = return (x + y)

incVal''' :: (Monad m, Num a) => a -> a -> a -> m a
incVal''' x y z = return (x + y + z)

main = do
    print(Just 9 >>= incVal')
```

I can Invoke `incVal'` with `>>=` (as shown in the above code). But I am not understanding how to invoke `incVal''` and `incVal'''` with `>>=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Applicative in combination with `join`.

First, you can apply the function to the args using `<$>` and `<*>`:

```
print (incVal'' <$> Just 5 <*> Just 37)
```

But this is not quite enough, because the result of this will be `Maybe (Maybe Int)`, due to how `<*>` works, so the line above would print `"Just (Just 42)"`.

So as a last step, to "unnest" the value, you can use [the `join` function](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-19.32/base-4.15.1.0/Control-Monad.html#v:join), which is a standard Monad operation:

```
print (join (incVal'' <$> Just 5 <*> Just 37))
```

And, of course, the same approach works for `incVal'''`:

```
print (join (incVal''' <$> Just 1 <*> Just 4 <*> Just 37))
```

Incidentally, even `incVal'` call can be expressed in the same terms, because a combination of `<$>` (aka `fmap`) and `join` is equivalent to `>>=`:

```
print (join (incVal' <$> Just 42))
```